# What is the proper way to add/represent development tasks (like refacturing) to a sprint?

Tags: agile, sprint, kanban-board

We coded something which works but is quite terrible. We have planned the refactoring of that piece of code in this sprint but since it doesn't really fit in a user story, how do we add or represent this? Nothing will change at front-end, just back-end.

Comment: Why do you think you need to represent it specially? The Sprint Backlog is the team's to manage, and refactoring should be part of any properly-planned agile estimate.

Comment: It's more that I don't really know where to put it. Do I move the User Story back to `In Progress` and add it as a task or do I put it somewhere else? That part of the code is of two sprints ago.

Comment: Forget the old story: it’s *new* work. The task belongs to whatever current story requires the refactoring, or its own story if refactoring *is* the deliverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, including:

- Add a task to the backlog that covers this (perhaps labelling it as technical debt)
- Add a technical sub-task to a story that is already in your backlog

In the second option, what you are saying is

> To complete this story and deliver a quality product to our team's definition of done we should include refactoring this piece of code

As an example, I worked with a team that wanted to replace a JavaScript library with a better version. They added the refactoring work as technical sub-tasks on a number of stories, each of which touched on different pages on a website. Once all of the stories had been completed they had also completed the library upgrade.

What I like about this approach is that it demonstrates that code quality is *built-in* to your delivery of functionality.